# How to highlight text usign type.js text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have installed this basic version of type.js but I am having an issue getting it to highlight the words. Here is my code. Bare in mind this is the standard output for Type.js basic.

```html
<h2 class="animated fadeInUp dealy-500 display-6 display-md-4 display-lg-3 font-weight-bold text-white">
  <span class='highlight'>
    <span id="typed"></span>
  </span>
</h2>
```

```js
new Typed('#typed', {
  strings: ['IT Support', 'Security Infastructure', 'Managed IT Support', 'Web Development & Design'],
  typeSpeed: 150,
  delaySpeed: 190,
  loop: true
});
```

https://codepen.io/Budhiluhoer/pen/GGaxxO

Comment: When i add the css to the span class it doesnt work, so this is where i am having an isssue.

Comment: The Codepen seems to work fine (even when you paste in the code from your question). Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: `When i add the css to the span class it doesnt work` Then it would make sense for you to show us that CSS

Comment: .highlight {
    display: inline;
    background: rgba(255,142,136,.2);
}

Comment: Thanks Rory, here is my CSS above, Yeah the text is working but my objective is to have the text highlighted, Here is my Disired outcome https://leap.mediumra.re/elements-typed-text.html

Comment: It appears to work fine: https://codepen.io/RoryMcCrossan/pen/PoqmRXZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS just add a background to your `span` just like this :

```css
#typed{
   background: #ff0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/thomas-lamothe/pen/dyoWmqL